# add archive bit on files older than 14 days via PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to setup a PowerShell script which will add an archive bit to all the files which are older than +14 days in a specific folder, for example `C:\Temp`.

This is possible via CMD, but how do I manage to add the `+a` bit only to files older than +14 days?

```
attrib +A C:\temp\*.*
```

Comment: Sorry i have just changed it into the +A :)

Answer (score 1):

First check that the attribute is present or not and then you can set that based on the condition. 
To toggle the archive bit, you can use a *Bitwise Exclusive Or (BXOR)* operator.

You can do something like this:

```
$path = "C:\foldername"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\folderpath" -Recurse -force | where {($_.LastwriteTime -lt  (Get-Date).AddDays(-14) ) -and (! $_.PSIsContainer)} 
$attrib = [io.fileattributes]::archive
Foreach($file in $files)
{
    If((Get-ItemProperty -Path $file.fullname).attributes -band $attrib)
    {
    "Attribute is present"
    }
    else
    {
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $file.fullname -Name attributes -Value ((Get-ItemProperty $file.fullname).attributes -BXOR $attrib)
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: `((Get-ItemProperty $file.fullname).attributes -BXOR $attrib)` Won't this unset the archive flag if it's already set?  I mean, I know you've got the if statement, but logically I think you want to use the `-bor` operator.

Comment: @BaconBits No. It toggles the attribute, but doesn't update the value on the file in-place. To change the attribute on the file you need to assign the value back to the `Attributes` property. The code does this only if the attribute isn't present in the first place.

Comment: @BaconBits: Yes, Ansgar has explained properly on this. It will only toggle if the first one is empty.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Yes, as I said, *I understand there's an if statement*.  My point is that taken by itself I never want to toggle an attribute, so as far as code reuse it's not as valuable.  I want to either *set* the bit (`$_.Attributes -bor [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Archive`) or *unset* the bit (`$_.Attributes -band (-bnot [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Archive)`).  If my if statement has a bug, a toggle will be very difficult to detect because its behavior changes.  That's why I want the call to always do the exact operation I want, like `chmod` and `attrib` require.

Comment: @user2602460: Acceptance of the answer would be appreciable.

Answer (score -1):

Simply filter for files older than 14 days and add "Archive" to their attributes:

```
$threshold = (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-14)

Get-ChildItem 'C:\Temp' | Where-Object {
    -not $_.PSIsContainer -and
    $_.LastWriteTime -lt $threshold -and
    -not ($_.Attributes -band [IO.FileAttributes]::Archive)
} | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Attributes += 'Archive'
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `$_.Attributes += 'Archive'` works if Archive is already set?  `FileAttributes.Archive + FileAttributes.Archive` = `FileAttributes.Device`.  It seems to set attributes to `FileAttributes.Normal` (i.e., unset archive) when I test it.  I would prefer `$_.Attributes = $_.Attributes -bor [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Archive`.

Comment: @BaconBits Ah, drat. I thought it would, but apparently `+=` toggles the flag. Well, that's remedied easily enough by adding a check for the presence of that attribute to the `Where-Object` filter. Thanks for the heads up.